# Ubuntu not able to boot up and fresh installlation also not possible

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, gnome

I messed up with my `ubuntu 15.10`. I was trying to gnome-desktop-environment by running the command s`udo apt-get install gnome-desktop-environment`, but I closed the process in between because I didn't select the Light Ubuntu option when I was asked (mentioned in an article somewhere). 
After than my `ubuntu` didn't start(displayed a black terminal like grub screen in which when I entered the command `boot`, it showed `load the kernel first` error) 
 So I decided to do a fresh installation using live usb but now it got stuck on ubuntu loading screen. I also tried `nomodeset` but that didn't work either. Then I deleted the ubuntu partitions from windows(but I couldn't delete one partition except all) and then I also did bootrec.exe /fixmbr . After then also , fresh installation would stuck and boot up. 
I want to install a fresh ubuntu alongside my present windows like I had earlier , How do I fix the mess I made?

**EDIT 1** I was able to completely remove the ubuntu by `fixmbr` command using recovery drive  and deleted the `ubuntu` folder in the `boot` directory in efi partition . I removed all the ubuntu partitions as well. But still I am not able to do a fresh installation of any linux distro. Before loading , `ACPI PCC Probe failed` Error is displayed and the loading screen never ends and the caps lock starts blinking infinitely. I also tried booting using `nomodeset` but then it displayed the following error `blk update request : I/O error , dev sda ,sector xxxxxx` 
I guess something is wrong with my graphics setting as I interrupted that gnome-environment installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
If you are able to boot into Windows.
Boot in to Windows OS. Type `diskmgmt.msc` in Run or command Prompt .
Using Disk Management delete the Ubuntu partition.
Now try installing Ubuntu.
After installation is made, if you have problem with boot menu.
Use Boot Repair to create a new boot entry for ubuntu or you can repair the boot menu entry.

Solution 2:
If you can't able delete partition.
Try to delete the partition using `diskpart.exe`

Solution 3:
Prepare Live Boot CD or USB with any of the linux distro probably use Ubuntu. Live Boot into Ubuntu.Use **Disks Application** which will list all the disks.You can delete the partition.Then Start Fresh Installation.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

A question  first,  can you boot into Windows?

If you can great,  you can ignore the next step.

if you can't,  you need to get Windows working first.  With your Windows CD,  get to a terminal and type 'fixmbr',  then reboot from the harddrive,  as GRUB overwrites the Master Boot Record that Windows needs to boot.

Next you need to get rid of any Linux files on the HD,  insert and boot from your Ubuntu media.   Choose the Live option,  NOT Install option.

Next,  if everything goes smoothly,  click on Computer and delete every Linux file listed. This should  then allow you to then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Ubuntu live cd.
Load into the Ubuntu live cd/dvd in the "Try Ubuntu" mode. Now open GParted and delete the correct partition. (You can find gparted in the unity or by installing it in the software center)
Now you can erase the correct partitionIn gparted. Click the install Ubuntu on the desktop top and follw the directions. Once the install is complet it will update your grub. If you still have issues booting into ubuntu run the live cd again and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

then run boot repair.

```
boot-repair
```

in the terminal.

If this does not help you you may want to check your bios settings for booting as well as updating your question with what you have already tried.

Comment: I am not able to boot into ubuntu , It only shows loading screen